# Javascript JSON creation creating an additional object

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create an JSON from another JSON using Javascript.

Here is my code.

```js
var data = [{
    "Id": "123",
    "Name": "Abc",
    "Amount": 110000
  },
  {
    "Id": "567",
    "Name": "DEF",
    "Amount": 98000
  },
  {
    "Id": "345",
    "Name": "XYZ",
    "Amount": 145000
  }
];

finalArray(data);

function finalArray(data) {
  var nArray = [];
  var subArray = new Object();
  subArray.total = 0;
  subArray.records = {};
  subArray.size = 0;
  data.forEach(item => {

    subArray.total += item.Amount;
    subArray.records += item;
    subArray.size += 1;
  });
  nArray.push(subArray);
  console.log(nArray);
};
```

Here In the final object, In records I'm getting the below output.

```
records: "[object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object]"
```

expected output is

```
records: "[object Object][object Object][object Object]"
```

where as in my actual data, I've 3 records in the input.

Please let me know where I'm going wrong.

Thanks

Comment: What is the shape of the result supposed to be?

Comment: In my input I've 3 records, where as In my output, it is showing 4 records. @0stone0

Comment: One of the `[object Object]`s is because you initialize `records` with `subArray.records = {};` , i.e. an object. Then you are trying to "add" another object with `subArray.records += item;`. This will result in `[object Object][object Object]` since you are "concatenating" two objects. It goes without saying that concatenating objects as string is wrong.

Comment: There isn't any trace of JSON in the code you posted. [JSON](https://json.org) is a text representation of some data structure. Your code works with objects and never attempts to produce an external representation of the data they contain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
function finalArray(data) {
  var nArray = [];
  var subArray = new Object();
  subArray.total = 0;
  subArray.records = []; // records must be array
  subArray.size = 0;
  data.forEach(item => {

    subArray.total += item.Amount;
    subArray.records.push(item); // need to push each item to records array
    subArray.size += 1;
  });
  nArray.push(subArray);
  console.log(nArray);
};
```

Comment: Thanks man. This worked great. Can you please let me know where I went wrong?

Comment: Ah #@firatozcevahir... Gotcha. Thanks a ton mate...

Answer (score 1):

Code has 2 mistakes.

1. record should be an `array` **not an** `object`
2. you need use `push` method to add data to record. **Not** `addition assignment (+=)`

```js
var data = [{
    "Id": "123",
    "Name": "Abc",
    "Amount": 110000
  },
  {
    "Id": "567",
    "Name": "DEF",
    "Amount": 98000
  },
  {
    "Id": "345",
    "Name": "XYZ",
    "Amount": 145000
  }
];

finalArray(data);

function finalArray(data) {
  var nArray = [];
  var subArray = new Object();
  subArray.total = 0;
  subArray.records = [];
  subArray.size = 0;
  data.forEach(item => {

    subArray.total += item.Amount;
    subArray.records.push(item);
    subArray.size += 1;
  });
  nArray.push(subArray);
  console.log(nArray);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your function to this-

```
function finalArray(data) {
  var nArray = [];
  var subArray = new Object();
  subArray.total = 0;
  subArray.records=[];
  subArray.size = 0;
  data.forEach(item => {
    
    subArray.total += item.Amount;
    subArray.records += item;    
    subArray.size += 1;
  });
  nArray.push(subArray);
  console.log(nArray);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an `array` to hold the original `items`.
Also, you'll need [`push`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp) to add an Object to an Array;

```js
var data = [{
    "Id": "123",
    "Name": "Abc",
    "Amount": 110000
  },
  {
    "Id": "567",
    "Name": "DEF",
    "Amount": 98000
  },
  {
    "Id": "345",
    "Name": "XYZ",
    "Amount": 145000
  }
];

finalArray(data);

function finalArray(data) {

  // New data
  let nArray = {};
  nArray.total = 0;
  nArray.size = 0;
  
  // Create an array inside nArray to hold original items
  nArray.records = [];
  
  data.forEach((item) => {
    nArray.total += item.Amount;
    nArray.size += 1;
    nArray.records.push(item);
  });
 
  console.log(nArray);
};
```